# Logarithmic function in complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Show that:
$$\cos[i\log(2+\sqrt3)]=2$$

I attempted by taking$(2+\sqrt3)$ into trigonometrical form but i am stuck
Please help me out.

Comment: Funfact: $2+\sqrt3=\tan(\frac5{12}\pi)$.  However I don't think this helps you, see Olivier's answer instead :)

Comment: What's the trigonometrical form of $2+\sqrt3$ ?

Comment: $\cos\left(x\,\mathrm{i}\right) = \,\mathrm{cosh}\left(x\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\cos z= \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}.
$$ Apply it with $z=i \log(2+\sqrt{3})$.